# What is the meaning of "have a big row" in friendship?

Tags: meaning

In friendship, what does *have a big row* mean?  Is it a common expression?  What about its style (formal or informal)?

Example:

> It is not long before Soosan falls out with Hooshang, and Kobra and
>   Han have a big row.

Comment: You need to show some signs of having tried to answer the question (from readily available resources) yourself.

Comment: This is a less-common meaning of *row*, meaning *[a noisy argument](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/row_19)*, or more broadly, *a serious disagreement about an issue between people, organizations, or countries*.

Comment: Note that this word rhymes with *cow*, not *low*. It is a homonym but not a homophone to the other meanings of *row*.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common [Br. Eng.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English) expression, but very uncommon in [Amer. Eng.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English) Anyway, [row](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/row_4)

> A noisy argument or fight

and [big](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big)

> Large in size

"It is not long before Soosan falls out with Hooshang, and Kobra and Han have a big row." means that "It happened soon after that Soosan had a disagreement with Hooshang, and Kobra and Han battled".

Answer (score 0):

It means to quarrel with someone,  more informal in style

Comment: If so,what about the opposite of it? if they do not quarrel (get on well) is there any expression with **row**?

Comment: The opposite of "having a row" is "not having a row".

Comment: I mean expression with row. big row---> small row ----> no row:)---> ?? row?

Comment: You may say: My friend and I never have rows, we get on so well together.

Comment: @amir you are asking a second question, why not edit your question and include your request. It might save it from being closed as off topic.