# BBC Headline - full meaning

Tags: vocabulary

The current headline reads:  FBI director sacking row.

Dictionaries have not helped, will someone help understand it in full? The last word is the most troubling.

Comment: See ["What is the meaning of a big row..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161741/what-is-the-meaning-of-have-a-big-row-in-friendship/161751#161751)

Comment: It's a row about a sacking. See dictionary for *row* and *sacking*.

Comment: a lot of FBI directors are queuing for the sack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "have a big row" in friendship?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161741/what-is-the-meaning-of-have-a-big-row-in-friendship)

Answer (score 3):

It's British English:

> ***[Sack](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sack)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 informal Dismiss from employment.
>   *‘any official found to be involved would be sacked on the spot’*

and

> ***[Row](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/row)***
>
> NOUN
>
> British  informal
>
> 1 A noisy acrimonious quarrel.
>   *‘they had a row and she stormed out of the house’*
>
> 1.1 A serious dispute.
>   *‘the director is at the centre of a row over policy decisions’*
>
> 1.2 A severe reprimand.
>   *‘I always got a row if I left food on my plate’*
>
> 2 A loud noise or uproar.
>   *‘if he's at home he must have heard that row’*

Basically, it's saying there's a big *uproar* over the *firing* of FBI Director Comey.

Answer (score 3):

It's a confusing headline for someone who isn't already familiar with the writing style.

In this case, a "row" (pronounced \ˈrau̇\, as opposed to \ˈrō\) is a British English word meaning "a noisy disturbance or quarrel." ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/row)) An American paper might more commonly use terms like "uproar."

The row is happening because the president decided to "sack" ("to dismiss[,] especially summarily") the director of the FBI. ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sack))